# What were the efforts made by the U.S. government to conserve forests?

Tags: united-states

What were the efforts made by the U.S. government to conserve forests after World War 1 and World War 2? Was any special community or group made to complete this task? If yes then how did it conserve forests?

Comment: Which government?

Comment: U.S.A @semaphore

Comment: I don't understand the relationship between world wars and forest conservation.

Comment: the main method to conserve forest is not letting anyone cut them down.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I don't understand it either (though this does not mean it's a bad question – not that I'm implying you implied it was)

Answer (score 5):

[The bulk of the work had already been](http://www.theodore-roosevelt.com/trenv.html) completed during Teddy Roosevelt's [term in office](http://www.nps.gov/thro/learn/historyculture/theodore-roosevelt-and-conservation.htm), with the creation of:

- 4 National Game preserves
- 5 National parks
- 18 National Monuments
- 24 Reclamation Projects
- 51 Federal Bird Preserves
- 150 National Forests; and
- 230 Million total acres set aside for the enjoyment of all

Modern sensitivities may disagree with Teddy's motivations as a well known big-game hunter, but he loved the outdoors and the American West and worked diligently while in office to preserve it for generations to come. [Roosevelt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodore_Roosevelt) upon taking office made

> *conservation a top priority, [establishing] a myriad of new national
>   parks, forests, and monuments in order to preserve the nation's
>   natural resources.*
>   [from the introduction to the Wikipedia article on Theodore Roosevelt*].

and again:

> *We have fallen heirs to the most glorious heritage a people ever
>   received, and each one must do his part if we wish to show that the
>   nation is worthy of its good fortune.*
>    [*[Theodore Roosevelt](http://www.nps.gov/thro/learn/historyculture/theodore-roosevelt-and-conservation.htm)*]

Comment: It all started with Yellowstone Park, by president Ulysses S. Grant on March 1, 1872.

Comment: It would be a more complete answer if you mention the National Park Service as well as the US Forest Service' formation and how they changed and developed

Comment: @CGCampbell: OP was specifically interested in forest preservation, so I chose to be lazy.

Comment: You could also add the BLM (Bureau of Land Management) to the list, as they actually manage more land - 264 million acres, vs 188 million in the National Forests.  Of course the lands are managed for somewhat different ends.  At least hereabouts (Great Basin), the National Forests tend to be in mountain ranges (where there actually are trees, sometimes :-)), while the BLM has the sagebrush-covered valleys.

Comment: @jamesqf: I attempted to look up details on the history of the various services that mange different types of resources, but for the most part I could not find any details before the reorganization in 1933 or thereabouts.